# Is JSON the Object itself or the String of an Object?

Tags: javascript, json

The question speaks for itself. JSON isn't a type. You have the function `JSON.stringify(object)`. My opinion is that the resulting String from this function is JSON, not the object which is stringified. And if that is true JSON would be a String ?

Comment: It's a specifically formatted string. That's why it stands for *"JavaScript Object Notation"*

Comment: You're editing your question as if the answers so far don't answer your question. Is there something you still don't understand?

Comment: No , the discussion we have here on slack https://athomcommunity.slack.com/messages/C04SUGZ9E/ is: is json a string or an object.  which also is the  title of this question. An argument was against json is a string  that in the body of my question  that json only could be produced by the JSON,stringify function , so could be misunderstood "is JSON.stringify a String" while the question still is as stated in the title. Because there is a huge amount of knowledge here on Stackoverflow , i felt the freedom to ask this question here.

Comment: Just wanted to check, did you get your answer? If you did, please accept one of them so that this question isn't left open unnecessarily. Otherwise, let us know what else you wanted to know.

Answer (score 7):

JSON (*JavaScript Object Notation*) is a way to format object data as a string. You are correct in saying JSON is not a type. `JSON.stringify(object)` takes an object and returns a string. The string will contain the data of the object, but in a human-readable form.

So JSON is the string of an object.

Answer (score 1):

JSON(**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation) is a file-format that uses human-readable text.

In the following snippet, you can see that I created a JavaScript object (*object*) then I used `JSON.stringify(object)` to get the JSON version (*string*). `typeof` is used to show you the type of the element next to it.

`typeof object` will give you the type of `object`

You can also notice that there are some changes. For example, properties names are wrapped with double quotes `" "`, the values are wrapped with double quotes instead of simple,...

```js
const object = {
  propertyA : "This is my value A",
  propertyB : [1,2,3],
  propertyC : {test: 'Nice'}
};

console.log(typeof object);
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: I'm not convinced the OP will understand `typeof` given he didn't seem to understand what JSON was, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Clonkex I have updated my answer. Nevertheless, OP can easily find the doc about it and the name is self-explanatory

Comment: You'd think so, but it's amazing how difficult it can be for a total newbie to find this kind of info ;) Good edit though, +1

Comment: @Clonkex I can totally understand ! I just wanted to add information to your good answer

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a Objects Notation (serialised), but JSON has specifice characteristics that it can be converted into/from specific syntax of String (for usage into different languages/platforms or for data transfer into different systems).

In javaScript :

to convert syntactically_correct_string to JSON we use `JSON.parse(inputStringHere)`,

and to convert a JSON into String we use `JSON.stringify(inputJSONobject)`.